# How to perform mathematical operations in java method?

Tags: java, math

I am trying to create a vowel counter. I have declared int numVowels and numConsanants. How do I add them together them multiply and use printVarValue to print it out.I have tried

```
int Varvalue = numVowels + numConstants;
int Varvalue = numVowels * numConstants;
```

> Error can't use two varvalues

Comment: Can you show your code please? And what problem are you facing?

Comment: *variable name is already used, you cannot declare it again* - Copied from below answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you're declaring the same variable twice:

```
int Varvalue = numVowels + numConstants;
int Varvalue = numVowels * numConstants;
^ this variable name is already used, you cannot declase it again
```

Simply change the name of the second variable to something else (preferably meaningful).

Comment: If this is really the only problem, then it is a typo question, and you should be voting to close, rather than answering.

Comment: *change the name of the second variable* - or remove the `int` to re-assign a new value to it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat if you change it to another variable  you get it to print there are more steps like taking the answer from numConstants and subtracting 5

Answer (score -1):

You declared same variable twice. Change your code to:

```
int varValue = numVowels + numConstants;

int varValue2 = numVowels * numConstants;
```

or

```
int varValue = numVowels + numConstants;

varValue = numVowels * numConstants;//this varValue will overwrite value from first equation, so this makes no sence
```

Comment: how can I connect it together for it to print ? if i want to take the answer and subtract 5?